# bash conditional construct not working as expected

Tags: bash

I am trying to see if 3 variables have the same value[DEFAULT] if not I want do other function. All variables in below script are exported to system environment.

```
#!/bin/bash
if [[ "$IOEngine" == "psync"  && ( "$TestType" == "read" || "randread" ) ]] && [[ ( "$DatasetSize" && "$BlockSize" && "$Threads" == "DEFAULT" ) ]]; then
    echo "all variables are Using DEFAULT"

elif [[ $IOEngine == "libaio"  && ( $TestType == "read" || "randread" ) ]] && [[ ( $DatasetSize || $BlockSize || $Threads || $FileSize || $RunTime == $preset ) ]]; then
   echo "all variables are Using DEFAULT"

else
    echo "one of the params is NON_DEFAULT"
    exit 1
fi
```

When I

```
"export DatasetSize=non_DEFAULT",
```

the output is not executing else construct but executing the block itself.

Output:

```
all variables are Using DEFAULT
```

Expected:

```
one of the params is NON_DEFAULT
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're taking an unsupported shortcut with this:

`"$TestType" == "read" || "randread"`

Use this instead:

`"$TestType" == "read" || "$TestType" == "randread"`

This has the same problem:

`"$DatasetSize" && "$BlockSize" && "$Threads" == "DEFAULT"`

Comment: Please see my comment above. are you saying in bash with operations we have to check each variable individually and can't be grouped?

Comment: You can group things with the case statement:  `case "$TestType" in read|randread) echo something ;; *) echo something else ;; esac`

Answer (score 2):

This

```
[[ $DatasetSize ]]
```

returns `0` (test passed) iff `$DatasetSize` evaluates to a string with the length of non-zero.

Your code never checks against the content of the variable. It only checks if the length is non-zero. For this reason the default value (of non-zero length) and any non-default value (of non-zero length) will lead to the same outcome.

---

*Probably* you didn't realize that `[[ $foo && $bar == "DEFAULT" ]]` is equivalent to this

```
[[ $foo && ( $bar == "DEFAULT" ) ]]
```

not to this

```
[[ $foo == "DEFAULT" && $bar == "DEFAULT" ]]
```

Similarly `[[ $foo == "a" || "b" ]]` is equivalent to

```
[[ ( $foo == "a" ) || "b" ]]
```

which is always true because `b` is a non-empty string. So this piece of code

```
[[ <whatever expression> && ( $TestType == "read" || "randread" ) ]]
```

can be reduced to `[[ <whatever expression> ]]`.

---

Also note these are not equivalent:

```
[[ $foo == $bar ]]
[[ $foo == "$bar" ]]
```

The string to the right of the `==` operator is considered a pattern. Unquoted `*` or `?` (and few other things, some depending on `extglob` shell option) are special, even if they come from the variable. Quoting prevents this. Where you use `$RunTime == $preset` make sure you don't need `$RunTime == "$preset"` instead.

Here `$foo` may or may not be double-quoted. In your original code all the unquoted variables don't need to be quoted, except maybe `$preset`, as stated above.

More information: [*When is double-quoting necessary?*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/68694/108618)

Comment: so can you please just adjust my expression? basically, you are saying each varible should evaluated individually and i can't check all their values in shortcut?

    if [[ "$IOEngine" == "psync"  && ( "$TestType" == "read" || $TestType" == "randread" ) ]] && [[ "$DatasetSize" == "DEFAULT && "$BlockSize" == "DEFAULT" ]]; then
if [[ "$IOEngine" == "psync"  && ( "$TestType" == "read" ||  "$TestType"  == "randread" ) ]] && [[ "$DatasetSize" == "DEFAULT && "$BlockSize" == "DEFAULT" ]]; then
        echo "all DEFAULT"

Comment: so how to check the content of the variable in fact a particular value?

Comment: @fmaabd I can't adjust your expression because I don't know what the logic should be. I can only guess it from your code but the fact it doesn't work implies I may not guess right. What you published in the comment looks *more sane* on the first glance. You check the content of a single variable with `[[ $IOEngine == "libaio" ]]` like you did; but to build logic you need `[[ test1 && test2 ]]` or `[[ test1 ]] && [[ test2 ]]` (similarly with `||`). Sole string is a test for it being of non-zero length, so `[[ $foo ]]` is like `[[ $foo != "" ]]`. I know no shortcuts.